# Click Not working when Scroll down to new posts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-adapter

i want to make app with json api and WordPress as backend. i can fetch the posts and it works fine untill first page, when i click on each post i can see the post detail as well, but on next page's post , click doesn't work and app crashes, the error i got is this:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.punjabidharti.myapplication/com.punjabidharti.myapplication.PostDetails}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
```

this is the adapter...

```
 private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
private Context mContext;
int total_types;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {
    this.dataset = mlist;
    this.mContext = context;

}
public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       TextView title, subtitle;
       ImageView imageView;

       public ImageTypeViewHolder (View itemView) {

           super(itemView);

           this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
           this.subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
           this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


       }
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);
    return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Model object = dataset.get(position);
    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText(object.title);
    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText(object.subtitle);


    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}



@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataset.size();
}
```

and this is how i load next page on scroll..

```
 recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
            // do something...

            yourURL = "https://punjabidharti.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=4514&per_page=10&page=2";

           
            getRetrofit();
            


        }
    });
```

and this is how i fetch posts via retrofit..

```
 public void getRetrofit(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
    String yourURl = yourURL.replace(baseURL,"");
    Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getPostInfo( yourURl);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
            Log.e("mainactivyt", " response "+ response.body());
            mListPost = response.body();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (response.body() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("main ", " title " + response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " " +
                            response.body().get(i).getId());
                    String tempdetails = response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString();
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("<p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("</p>", "");
                    tempdetails = tempdetails.replace("[&hellip;]", "");
                    list.add(new Model(Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                            tempdetails,
                            response.body().get(i).getLinks().getWpFeaturedmedia().get(0).getHref()));
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: the size of the array list is 10 so when you click then it's expected index 11 while there is no data on index 11. therefore it will be crashed.

Comment: check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244384/14630265

Comment: yes , how can i update code for next 10 posts ? @AnwarZahid

Comment: changing the loop from (<) this to (<=) in the getRetrofit method where you add the model to the list.

Comment: i have tried that but did not work @AnwarZahid

Comment: Add complete adapter I will edit to you.

Comment: @AnwarZahid that is my complete adapter

Answer (score 0):

change Adapter and also ArrayList to List.

```
public class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageTypeViewHolder.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Model> dataset;
    private Context mContext;
    int total_types;
    public ImageTypeViewHolder(List<Model> mlist, Context context) {
        this.dataset = mlist;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);
        return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(dataset.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.subtitle.setText(dataset.get(position).getSubTitle());
        holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size();
    }

    public  static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title, subtitle;
        ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting error here View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);
            return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);

"Expected 2 arguments but found 1"

and here 

holder.title.setText(dataset.get(position).getTitle());
            holder.subtitle.setText(dataset.get(position).getSubTitle());

getTitle and getSubTitle is red

Comment: This won't work how are you returning `new ImageTypeViewHolder(view)` in `onCreateViewHolder` You should return `new ViewHolder(view)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageTypeViewHolder.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Model> dataset;
    private Context mContext;
    public ImageTypeViewHolder(List<Model> mlist, Context context) {
        this.dataset = mlist;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.postdetails, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(dataset.get(position).getTitle(),dataset.get(position).getSubTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title, subtitle;
        ImageView imageView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
       private void setData(String title, String subtitle){
           this.title.setText(title);
           this.subtitle.setText(subtitle);
       }
       
       title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

       subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent (mContext, PostDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra ("itemPosition", position);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting this error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10"  @Swapnil Padaya

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.punjabidharti.myapplication/com.punjabidharti.myapplication.PostDetails}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.punjabidharti.myapplication.PostDetails.onCreate(PostDetails.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)

Comment: The actual problem isn't there in the adapter, Its  in PostDetails Activity.

Comment: this is my post details : 

Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("itemPosition");

        Log.e("PostDetails ", "title is " + MainActivity.mListPost.get(position).getTitle().getRendered());

        this.title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        title.setText(Html.fromHtml(MainActivity.mListPost.get(position).getTitle().getRendered()));



        String data = String.valueOf((Html.fromHtml(MainActivity.mListPost.get(position).getContent().getRendered())));

Comment: Create a room and share me the details there, And there's some problem in  your `PostDeatils` `onCreate` Method

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/230385/punjabidharti